# Hardware decoding with OMXCodec

Tags: android, header, decoding

I am trying to use OMXCodec in my project. The only good tutorial about OMXCodec that I found is this [post](https://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk) . However, the author doesn't mention how to write and get the header files and how to set up Android.mk. I really feel confused. My question is how I can find the header files and set up to make these codes work.

```
#define FFMPEG_AVFORMAT_MOV "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2"

using namespace android;

class AVFormatSource : public MediaSource {
  public:
    AVFormatSource(const char *videoPath);

    virtual status_t read(MediaBuffer **buffer, const MediaSource::ReadOptions *options);
    virtual sp<MetaData> getFormat() { return mFormat; }
    virtual status_t start(MetaData *params) { return OK; }
    virtual status_t stop() { return OK; }

  protected:
    virtual ~AVFormatSource();

  private:
    AVFormatContext *mDataSource;
    AVCodecContext *mVideoTrack;
    AVBitStreamFilterContext *mConverter;
    MediaBufferGroup mGroup;
    sp<MetaData> mFormat;
    int mVideoIndex;
};

AVFormatSource::AVFormatSource(const char *videoPath) {
  av_register_all();

  mDataSource = avformat_alloc_context();
  avformat_open_input(&mDataSource, videoPath, NULL, NULL);
  for (int i = 0; i < mDataSource->nb_streams; i++) {
    if (mDataSource->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      mVideoIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  mVideoTrack = mDataSource->streams[mVideoIndex]->codec;

  size_t bufferSize = (mVideoTrack->width * mVideoTrack->height * 3) / 2;
  mGroup.add_buffer(new MediaBuffer(bufferSize));
  mFormat = new MetaData;

  switch (mVideoTrack->codec_id) {
    case CODEC_ID_H264:
      mConverter = av_bitstream_filter_init("h264_mp4toannexb");
      mFormat->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
      if (mVideoTrack->extradata[0] == 1) {
        mFormat->setData(kKeyAVCC, kTypeAVCC, mVideoTrack->extradata, mVideoTrack->extradata_size);
      }
      break;
    case CODEC_ID_MPEG4:
      mFormat->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_MPEG4);
      if (mDataSource->iformat && mDataSource->iformat->name && !strcasecmp(mDataSource->iformat->name, FFMPEG_AVFORMAT_MOV)) {
        MOVContext *mov = (MOVContext *)(mDataSource->priv_data);
        if (mov->esds_data != NULL && mov->esds_size > 0 && mov->esds_size < 256) {
          mFormat->setData(kKeyESDS, kTypeESDS, mov->esds_data, mov->esds_size);
        }
      }
      break;
    case CODEC_ID_H263:
      mFormat->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_H263);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  mFormat->setInt32(kKeyWidth, mVideoTrack->width);
  mFormat->setInt32(kKeyHeight, mVideoTrack->height);
}

status_t AVFormatSource::read(MediaBuffer **buffer, const MediaSource::ReadOptions *options) {
  AVPacket packet;
  status_t ret;
  bool found = false;

  while (!found) {
    ret = av_read_frame(is->formatCtx, &packet);
    if (ret < 0) {
      return ERROR_END_OF_STREAM;
    }

    if (packet.stream_index == mVideoIndex) {
      if (mConverter) {
        av_bitstream_filter_filter(mConverter, mVideoTrack, NULL, &packet.data, &packet.size, packet.data, packet.size, packet.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY);
      }
      ret = mGroup.acquire_buffer(buffer);
      if (ret == OK) {
        memcpy((*buffer)->data(), packet.data, packet.size);
        (*buffer)->set_range(0, packet.size);
        (*buffer)->meta_data()->clear();
        (*buffer)->meta_data()->setInt32(kKeyIsSyncFrame, packet.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY);
        (*buffer)->meta_data()->setInt64(kKeyTime, packet.pts);
      }
      found = true;
    }
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }

  return ret;
}

AVFormatSource::~AVFormatSource() {
  if (mConverter) {
    av_bitstream_filter_close(mConverter);
  }
  av_close_input_file(mDataSource);
}
```

and decoding part:

```
// At first, get an ANativeWindow from somewhere
sp<ANativeWindow> mNativeWindow = getNativeWindowFromSurface();

// Initialize the AVFormatSource from a video file
sp<MediaSource> mVideoSource = new AVFormatSource(filePath);

// Once we get an MediaSource, we can encapsulate it with the OMXCodec now
OMXClient mClient;
mClient.connect();
sp<MediaSource> mVideoDecoder = OMXCodec::Create(mClient.interface(), mVideoSource->getFormat(), false, mVideoSource, NULL, 0, mNativeWindow);
mVideoDecoder->start();

// Just loop to read decoded frames from mVideoDecoder
for (;;) {
    MediaBuffer *mVideoBuffer;
    MediaSource::ReadOptions options;
    status_t err = mVideoDecoder->read(&mVideoBuffer, &options);
    if (err == OK) {
        if (mVideoBuffer->range_length() > 0) {
            // If video frame availabe, render it to mNativeWindow
            sp<MetaData> metaData = mVideoBuffer->meta_data();
            int64_t timeUs = 0;
            metaData->findInt64(kKeyTime, &timeUs)
            native_window_set_buffers_timestamp(mNativeWindow.get(), timeUs * 1000);
            err = mNativeWindow->queueBuffer(mNativeWindow.get(), mVideoBuffer->graphicBuffer().get());
            if (err == 0) {
                metaData->setInt32(kKeyRendered, 1);
            }
        }
        mVideoBuffer->release();
    }
}

// Finally release the resources
mVideoSource.clear();
mVideoDecoder->stop();
mVideoDecoder.clear();
mClient.disconnect();
```

Comment: just tell me what is your general task? (video convector?)

Comment: You can find OMXCodec.h and OMXClient.h [here](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/include/media/stagefright?h=jb_mr1).

Comment: @Vladimir I am trying to build a video player on android. Previously I use libavcodec to decode video frames. However, it is slow. There are some posts suggesting that using OMXCodec to decode video would be faster. But the tutorials about OMXCodec are so limited.

Comment: @JohnSimpson You should use native (written on C) decoder. But first. did you try to use Android MediaCodec (16 Api)? I'm using it for audio, but it should decode video to.

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, I have tried using MediaCodec. It could decode both audio and video. However, I want to do decoding in the native code so that I could process the decoded frames for example cropping and scaling. As far as I know, MediaCodec API is quite inflexible to do that tasks.

Comment: I have resolved the problem. I have to clone the android source project https://android.googlesource.com/, then set LOCAL_C_INCLUDES points to the folders that contain the header files.

Comment: @JohnSimpson, you didn't have to install your cloned android source onto your device, correct? That is, you only needed the source for the compilation of your app, right?

Comment: @t2k32316, yes exactly